# How can I use 32-bit Perl to thaw something frozen with 64-bit Storable?

Tags: perl, endianness, storable

I'm trying to thaw a database BLOB that was frozen using Storable on a 64-bit Solaris (production) machine. When I try to thaw on a 32-bit Windows (development) PC I receive "Byte order is not compatible error".

```
perl -v (on solaris)
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i86pc-solaris-64

perl -v (on Windows)
This is perl, v5.10.1 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
```

Exact error is:

```
(Unable to read: Byte order is not compatible at blib\lib\Storable.pm (autosplit into  blib\lib\auto\Storable\thaw.al) line 415, at ../handlers/Search/actions/SearchSendQueue.pm line 124 )
```

line 124 of SearchSendQueue.pm:

```
my $object = thaw( $item->{object} );
```

Does anybody know how I can thaw this object on the 32-bit machine?

Note: The object is valid and working on the 64 bit production machine. 
I've already tried "$Storable::interwork_56_64bit = 1;" as suggested on other forums.

Comment: If it's just a byte ordering issue, you could try reversing the byte order with pack()?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but 64-bit Intel machines are cheap and Solaris is free. Even if you want to mostly run Windows, a Solaris virtual machine can help. I'm quite happy that I can use one machine to develop on almost any platform I choose. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Storable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable#64_bit_data_in_perl_5.6.0_and_5.6.1) documentation says:

> Storable writes a file header which contains the sizes of various C language types for the C compiler that built Storable (when not writing in network order), and will refuse to load files written by a Storable not on the same (or compatible) architecture.

In the same section, they suggest that the basic use of Storable is a local and *FAST* persistence method. However, you can use `nstore` to store the persisted structure in *network* byte order. The result will be that it reads and stores slower but works across all platforms.

So the suggestion is that you'll have to use the 64-bit machine to read and re-store the data in network order using `nstore`.

Comment: Does that work for 32/64-bit gaps or just for big-endian/little-endian CPUs?

Comment: @fennec: That should work for completely portable Storable files. The section I referenced deals specifically with 64-bit architectures.

Comment: I was trying to avoid thaw / nfreeze on the production server. However, it seemed to be the only way, so that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 5):

I know the docs indicate it's supposed to be possible, but I've never been able to get it to work except by using nfreeze/nstore* on the the 64-bit machine.